# I can't start android studio on windows 8

Tags: android, android-studio

Please help me. I want to start developing on Android. I downloaded Android Studio for windows, and installed it, but when I double click on it to open it, it shows this:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.btr.proxy.search.desktop.win.Win32ProxyUtils
    at com.btr.proxy.search.browser.ie.IEProxySearchStrategy.readSettings(IEProxySearchStrategy.java:57)
    at com.btr.proxy.search.browser.ie.IEProxySearchStrategy.getProxySelector(IEProxySearchStrategy.java:42)
    at com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch.getProxySelector(ProxySearch.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.net.IdeaWideProxySelector.select(IdeaWideProxySelector.java:86)
    at com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy.select(CommonProxy.java:232)
    at com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy.select(CommonProxy.java:199)
    at com.intellij.util.net.HttpConfigurable.openConnection(HttpConfigurable.java:366)
    at com.intellij.util.net.HttpConfigurable.openHttpConnection(HttpConfigurable.java:394)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.checkInternetConnection(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.fetchPackages(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.access$100(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$2.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$2.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$4.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:240)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149
```

I already have Java, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Try going to the Android Studio setup folder, and running studio64.exe

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: Yes more than 20 times

Comment: Not sure if you can select it but did you select the same bit version as your os?

Comment: Try removing your java libray. Does the error change?

Comment: Yes thank's very much

Comment: Yes thank's very much

Answer (score 0):

Just try to uninstall and reinstall it, sometimes if something isn't working just try that. Also check if you installed the newest version of android studio. If nothing works just type it into google or youtube maybe you will find someone that had the same probelm.And btw you don't need java its just "in" andorid studio.

Comment: This is a comment or suggestion. Not an answer. So its better to keep the comments or suggestions under comment not on the answer field.